# No "Variable is assigned but never used" warning

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code, I'm using VS 2012 and all my warnings are treated as errors (although this probably doesn't have much relevance).

```
private static readonly int MAX_RADIUS_KM = 16;

private void Test() {
    int i = 2 * MAX_RADIUS_KM;
    int i2 = 2;
}
```

"The variable [x] is assigned, but its value is never used" is shown for `i2`, but not for `i`. Why? Is this a bug or something's happening behind the scenes? I'd be surprised by the latter, but if so, what's happening that makes `i` to avoid that warning?

The following also exhibits failure to emit warning for unused `i`:

```
private void Test(int foo) {
    int i = 2 * foo;
    int i2 = 2;
}
```

And another (`i2` in this case):

```
private void Test()
{
  int i = 2 * 3;
  int i2 = i;
}
```

Comment: I would say it is a bug. What version of VS are you using? And is it vanilla? My version of VS (11.0.61030.00 Update 4) with Reshaper (7.1.3000.2254) says that both are never used.

Comment: same in VS2103 ultimate

Comment: @Jonny I'm using the very same version of VS you are using, but without Resharper.

Comment: This only fails to warn in the case where `readonly` is present and when a parameter is used. Warns with `const` and other cases.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Why do you think that? This question is not about FIELDS. It's about local variables. Am I missing something? (tbh I didn't have enough time to study the other question. There MAY be things in common, but that doesn't make the questions identical)

Comment: It describes the same problem and I think the answer is the same too. It isn't an exact duplicate, but I think it is close enough.

Comment: For the record: replacing `static int` by `const` fixes the issue